# Is there a way "extract and delete zip file" in a single command?

Tags: zip

Is there a way (preferrable via GUI, but may be via command line) to extract a zip file and delete the zip after extracted, all in a single command?

(I remember I saw someone doing something like this in the command line one day)

Comment: I am not aware of single command but you can queue second command.
unzip 1.zip; rm 1.zip

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For a GUI I'd say the easiest way is a nautilus script. The main line of which would be:

```
unzip "$item" && trash "$item"
```

It works in bash/dash just as easy. In nautilus the whole thing would look like this:

[image: unzip delete nautilus script]

```
#!/bin/bash
# Nautilus script to unzip and then remove a zip archive.
# Nautilus script usually go in "$HOME/.gnome2/nautilus-scripts"

IFS='
'
for item in $NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS; do
    if [ -n "$(file -b "$item" | grep -o 'Zip')" ]; then
        unzip "$item" && trash "$item"
        # use trash instead of rm to move them to trash
        # (trash-cli package installed)
    fi
done
```

Comment: In case we have a memory storage issue, how can we unzip a huge zip file and erase the unzipped parts at the same time to avert a memory overflow ?

Answer (score 11):

You could simply write a bash script. It will look something like this:

```
unzip $1 && rm $1
```

where $1 is the argument with a value of your zip file's filename. Then alias unzip command in ~/.bashrc file to run this script. And after typing in terminal:

```
unzip test.zip
```

you will get:

```
unzip test.zip && rm test.zip
```

Comment: There is no need for the `-r` flag here. Zip files are not directories so there is nothing to recurse into.

Answer (score 4):

It's pretty easy through a shell command:

`unzip <filename>.zip && rm <filename>.zip`

Perhaps, if you're using nautilus, you could create a relevant `nautilus-action` in order to automate the command through a GUI selection.

Comment: yeah, actually these are 2 commands in a single line.. I'm really trying to remember the single command I saw someone use..

Comment: I don't see how it matters whether it's one or two command. You sure he did use an alias or was in fact compressing and used `tar --delete-files`?

Comment: It matters if you are going to use the command as entrypoint for a container.